# modify strings in python dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of device IDs (as a key) and addresses (as values).

What I am trying to do is flag address that are an IP address and modify the string to include a ':47808' to the original IP address string. For example an IP address like this `'10.200.200.26'` modify to `'10.200.200.26:47808'`

These types of addresses like this `11:11` are twisted pair rs-485 devices that can be left alone.

```
data = {
    
    5242: '10.200.200.202', 
    5237: '10.200.200.191', 
    5233: '10.200.200.194', 
    5235: '10.200.200.193', 
    5241: '10.200.200.201', 
    5240: '10.200.200.200', 
    5239: '10.200.200.198', 
    5231: '10.200.200.196', 
    5232: '10.200.200.195', 
    5238: '10.200.200.190', 
    5236: '10.200.200.192', 
    5230: '10.200.200.197', 
    5234: '10.200.200.199', 
    10000: '10.200.200.26', 
    1100: '10.200.200.27', 
    1002: '10.200.200.32', 
    4: '11:4', 
    73005: '11:5',
     6: '11:6',
     7: '11:7',
     8: '11:8',
     22: '12:22',
     9: '11:9',
     23: '12:23',
     10: '11:10',
     24: '12:24',
     11: '11:11',
     25: '12:25',
     12: '11:12',
     12026: '12:26',
     27: '12:27',
     13: '11:13',
     12028: '12:28',
     14: '11:14',
     29: '12:29',
     30: '12:30',
     15: '11:15',
     31: '12:31',
     16: '11:16',
     12032: '12:32',
     12033: '12:33',
     73017: '11:17',
     34: '12:34',
     73018: '11:18',
     12035: '12:35',
     19: '11:19',
     36: '12:36',
     20: '11:20',
     21: '11:21',
     37: '11:37',
     38: '11:38',
     39: '11:39'
}
```

Can someone give me a tip on how to do this? I am trying the `.find` to flag `:` character as Boolean check that would only be in the type of address that can be left alone.

```
def isIPadress(stringVal):
    return stringVal.find(':')

for device,address in data.items():
    print(isIPadress(address))
```

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does this code give you? How does it differ from your expectations? Have you done any [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? You are expected to do basic diagnosis [before asking here.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) For example: `stringVal.find(':')` returns an _integer_. Why do you expect it to be a boolean? Did you read the documentation to find out what happens if the string you're looking for doesn't exist in the search string? Where do you modify the value in the dict if you determine that it is an IP address? Please post a  [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this
note that IP address checking is very simple but works for this data set.

```
data = {
    5242: '10.200.200.202',
    5237: '10.200.200.191',
    5233: '10.200.200.194',
    5235: '10.200.200.193',
    5241: '10.200.200.201',
    5240: '10.200.200.200',
    5239: '10.200.200.198',
    5231: '10.200.200.196',
    5232: '10.200.200.195',
    5238: '10.200.200.190',
    5236: '10.200.200.192',
    5230: '10.200.200.197',
    5234: '10.200.200.199',
    10000: '10.200.200.26',
    1100: '10.200.200.27',
    1002: '10.200.200.32',
    4: '11:4',
    73005: '11:5',
    6: '11:6',
    7: '11:7',
    8: '11:8',
    22: '12:22',
    9: '11:9',
    23: '12:23',
    10: '11:10',
    24: '12:24',
    11: '11:11',
    25: '12:25',
    12: '11:12',
    12026: '12:26',
    27: '12:27',
    13: '11:13',
    12028: '12:28',
    14: '11:14',
    29: '12:29',
    30: '12:30',
    15: '11:15',
    31: '12:31',
    16: '11:16',
    12032: '12:32',
    12033: '12:33',
    73017: '11:17',
    34: '12:34',
    73018: '11:18',
    12035: '12:35',
    19: '11:19',
    36: '12:36',
    20: '11:20',
    21: '11:21',
    37: '11:37',
    38: '11:38',
    39: '11:39'
}
with_port = {}
for k,v in data.items():
    if v.count('.') == 3:
        with_port[k] = f'{v}:47808'
    else:
        with_port[k] = v
for k,v in with_port.items():
    print(f'{k} -->  {v}')
```

output

```
5242 -->  10.200.200.202:47808
5237 -->  10.200.200.191:47808
5233 -->  10.200.200.194:47808
5235 -->  10.200.200.193:47808
5241 -->  10.200.200.201:47808
5240 -->  10.200.200.200:47808
5239 -->  10.200.200.198:47808
5231 -->  10.200.200.196:47808
5232 -->  10.200.200.195:47808
5238 -->  10.200.200.190:47808
5236 -->  10.200.200.192:47808
5230 -->  10.200.200.197:47808
5234 -->  10.200.200.199:47808
10000 -->  10.200.200.26:47808
1100 -->  10.200.200.27:47808
1002 -->  10.200.200.32:47808
4 -->  11:4
73005 -->  11:5
6 -->  11:6
7 -->  11:7
8 -->  11:8
22 -->  12:22
9 -->  11:9
23 -->  12:23
10 -->  11:10
24 -->  12:24
11 -->  11:11
25 -->  12:25
12 -->  11:12
12026 -->  12:26
27 -->  12:27
13 -->  11:13
12028 -->  12:28
14 -->  11:14
29 -->  12:29
30 -->  12:30
15 -->  11:15
31 -->  12:31
16 -->  11:16
12032 -->  12:32
12033 -->  12:33
73017 -->  11:17
34 -->  12:34
73018 -->  11:18
12035 -->  12:35
19 -->  11:19
36 -->  12:36
20 -->  11:20
21 -->  11:21
37 -->  11:37
38 -->  11:38
39 -->  11:39
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find ip addresses and then append the port to their value in the dictionary:

```
import regex as re
data = {
    5242: '10.200.200.202', 
    4: '11:4', 
}
for key in data.keys():
    if re.match(r'^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$', data[key]):
        data[key] = data[key] + ':47808'
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regular expression to find out if a string is an IP address, and if it is just add the port suffix you want, something like that

```py
ip_regex = re.compile('^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$')

def normalize_address(address):
    return address + ':47808' if ip_regex.match(address) else address

data = {...}

data_with_address = {key:normalize_address(address) for key,address in data.items()}
```